# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException no matter how hard i try

Tags: java, arrays

EDIT: For people who stumble upon this post i fixed my problem by using ArrayList instead of normal Arrays - doing so cut out about a 3rd of my code and made a lot of it reusable. Thanks to all who helped out below. Here is a link to my updated code for those who are on the hunt: http://pastebin.com/Yh3LVu2H

The program is meant to read the lines of a file and output them into two arrays xAxis and yAxis - iv split it up over two files because i will use ScreenSizes.java to also construct the GUI.

I'm getting the exception on the line "System.out.println("X: " + xAxis[index]);"

Code from ScreenSizes.java:

```
package screensizes;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ScreenSizes{    

    public String filePath = "/Users/jonny/Documents/UNI/ScreenSizes/xy.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    ScreenSizes obj = new ScreenSizes();
        obj.run();
    }

    public void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
        GetScreens data = new GetScreens(filePath);
        int noLines = data.countLines();
        int[] xAxis = data.getData('x');
        int[] yAxis = data.getData('y');
    int index = 0;
        while(index<noLines){
        System.out.println("X: " + xAxis[index]);
        index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Code from GetScreens.java

```
package screensizes;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GetScreens
{

    public int lines;
    public String filePath = "";
    public int[] x = new int[lines];    
    public int[] y = new int[lines];

    public GetScreens(String aFileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        fFile = new File(aFileName);
        filePath = aFileName;
        try
        {
        processLineByLine();
        countLines();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public final void processLineByLine() throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Note that FileReader is used, not File, since File is not Closeable
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(fFile));
        try {
            while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ){
                processLine( scanner.nextLine() );
            }
        }
        finally {
            //ensure the underlying stream is always closed
            //this only has any effect if the item passed to the Scanner
            //constructor implements Closeable (which it does in this case).
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    public int[] getData(char choice){
        if(choice == 'x'){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            return y;
        }
    }

    public void processLine(String aLine){
        //use a second Scanner to parse the content of each line 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(aLine);
        scanner.useDelimiter("x");
        if ( scanner.hasNext() ){
           for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){            
                x[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                y[i] = scanner.nextInt();
           }
        }
        else {
            log("Empty or invalid line. Unable to process.");
        }
    }

    public int countLines(){
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
            reader.close();
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
        }

        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        return lines;
    }

    // PRIVATE 
    public final File fFile;

    private void log(Object aObject){
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(aObject));
    }

    private String quote(String aText){
        String QUOTE = "'";
        return QUOTE + aText + QUOTE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Or even "dirty" println statements to see what is going on?

Comment: try to print the value that is returned from "data.getData('x')" a couple of lines before teh exception

Comment: Yeah iv done that its fine up until:
int[] xAxis = data.getData('x');
int[] yAxis = data.getData('y');

Before that if i println either of the arrays they output the correct number at the specified element [0 because theyre empty].

noLines is also being calculated correctly and prints as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok if i add:
System.out.println(data.getData('x'));
It ouputs: [I@33db4f6f

Comment: @Jonny: Print Array by first `import java.util.Arrays`, then in the print statement `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`

Comment: Ah thanks :) i think iv fixed some of my problem with the posts below, got an issue with NoSuchElementException in processLine() now - ah well ill keep at it!. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use arrays you have to first count the lines with `countLines()`, then initialize the arrays with

```
 x = new int[lines];
 y = new int[lines];
```

and then you can actually start to process...

Results in something like this:

```
public GetScreens(String aFileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    fFile = new File(aFileName);
    filePath = aFileName;
    try
    {
        countLines();
        x = new int[lines];
        y = new int[lines];
        processLineByLine();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But this code/ design is very likely to produce more errors when used later on. I'd rather think of using returnvalues for your functions. (For example if you execute `countLines()` twice you'll end up with double the lines you actually have in that file...

I think using `ArrayList` would make your code much more safe.

Comment: Good point about countLines() - and having had a look at ArrayList i think your right. Ill have another go at the same problem using ArrayLists instead.

Thanks heaps!
_j

Comment: @Jonny If you are satisfied with an answer to your question you should mark it so and accept that answer by clicking the check mark of that answer.

Comment: Aha! Until now i thought you had to have rep points to mark questions as answered - thanks! And thanks for the pointer about ArrayList - so, so much easier! Iv edited my original post with a link to my updated code for posterity.

Comment: @Jonny You're welcome. I just had a peek into your code. Depending on your problem instead of using two lists I'd rather use one to store a coordinate-pair, which would be more efficient and keep your model closer to reality. It's also less error-prone. (An error here: `y.add(scanner.next());` may result in having the two lists containing different amounts of elements!) You should also consider "typing" your List for better readability (for example `ArrayList<String>`). Also remember that `countLines()` is only the **maximum** number of elements in each array!

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-initlialize the `int[] x` and `int[] y` according to no of records in file.

Comment: Sorry not sure i quite follow you - i need to initialize x[] and y[] in ScreenSizes.java? is that what you mean?

Comment: You are initializing you arrays with new int[lines], lines is zero, so you are creating array with zero size. in you processLineByLine, you need to determine the no of lines and then initiliaze the array with that size, or instead use ArrayList, that can be converted to array if required.

Comment: ok that makes sense, but if im already doing that at the top:

public int[] x = new int[countLines()];    
    public int[] y = new int[countLines()];

Should i need to do it in the processLineByLine method? I wouldnt have thought so :S

Answer (score 0):

In your `GetScreens` class, the instance variable `lines` is being implicitly initialized to `0`. Consequently your `x` and `y` arrays are of length zero: no elements.

And so when you try to use them in your other class you'll get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Initialize `lines` to something useful.

When you compile your programs keep an eye out for warnings such as: `The variable _lines_ may not have been initialized`.

Comment: How so? It shouldnt be - if i add a System.out.println(noLines); to ScreenSizes.java it outputs the correct number of lines... so that looks like its working. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem. If you don't explicitly initialize a variable in java, e.g. `int lines;` then it is implicitly initialized to zero (or false, or null).

Comment: Ok that makes sense - looks like iv fixed that now. Now im getting a NoSuchElementException in processLine() even though im using hasNext() *sigh*

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] x = new int[lines];    
public int[] y = new int[lines];
```

is as good as:

```
public int[] x = new int[0];    
public int[] y = new int[0];
```

do this before using them:

```
x = new int[countLines()];    
y = new int[countLines()];
```

--V

Answer (score 0):

@Jonny

In processLine method you have given

for(int i=0; i< lines; i++)

{

```
            x[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            y[i] = scanner.nextInt();
```

}

but dont understand logic behind that you cant scanner.nextInt() to x[i] and y[i].In assigning the x[i] and y[i] is the main problem

use

```
           x[i] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());

           y[i] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
```

Comment: AHA! thanks! I was looking in completely the wrong place... I will note that for next time! [id up vote but i havnt enough rep sorry...]

Comment: @jonny: wait even though you wont get the output with that code

Comment: Weird, its still throwing a NoSuchElementException - ill keep looking :)

Comment: Well i havnt added the for loop to print out the contents of the xAxis and yAxis array - but they should both be an array with 139 elements each element containing a number fetched from the text file.

Heres a copy of the source with additions from this topic;
http://pastebin.com/QNxjAP3h

Comment: So i need to make 'throwaway' variables to hold the contents of scanner.nextInt(); before assigning it to x[i] / y[i]?

Comment: All the content in your text file numeric or even character also?

Comment: its display resolutions so a list like: 16x16 80x90 100x150 [with a line break between each set]. Im using the x as the delimiter...

Comment: @jonny : can i change your code??? or shall i send example files similar to this that can help you

Comment: Go for it - i may well have made an error in my algorithm that is fatally flawed. Any help on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: which ever is easier for you. Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Naveen - looking through it now and redesigning my code :)